# xsim problem with reverse synctex

Tags: forward-inverse-search, xsim

I am possibly experiencing  a strange behaviour with package `xsim` while working with reverse synctex (from document to source).

### Expected behaviour

I activate reverse synctex in my IDE, then I get pointed at the relevant line in the respective source code upon clicking inside the document.

### Observed behaviour

For environments defined with `xsim`, reverse synctex only points to the end of the environment.
This behaviour happend for all `xsim` environments, regardless if I define them myself or use the provided `exercise-template = default` .

### MWE

See the following MWE to evaluate the behaviour yourself:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

% option blank does not use any pre-defined xsim environments
\usepackage[no-files, blank]{xsim}
\usepackage{amsthm}

%  create my own exercise environment
\DeclareExerciseType{exercise}{
    exercise-env = exercise,
    solution-env = solution,
    exercise-name = \XSIMtranslate{exercise},
    exercises-name = \XSIMtranslate{exercises},
    solution-name = \XSIMtranslate{solution},
    solutions-name = \XSIMtranslate{solutions},
    exercise-template = xsimTemplateMWE,
    solution-template = xsimTemplateMWE,
}

% declare an xsim template
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{xsimTemplateMWE}{
    \vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
    Exercise:
}{%
    \par%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
    \vspace{\belowdisplayskip}%
}

% declare custom environment for comparison
\NewDocumentEnvironment{test}{ O{} }{%
    \vspace{\abovedisplayskip}%
    \noindent\ignorespaces%
    Test:
    }{
    \par%
    \ignorespacesafterend%
    \vspace{\belowdisplayskip}%
}

%  declare a amsthm environment based on trivlist for comparison
\newtheorem{testthm}{Testtheorem}


\begin{document}
\begin{exercise}
    This is Exercise~1.

    Notice, that if you reverse synctex (from document to source), your cursor will be at the end of the exercise environement, regardless where you clicked at.

    You can also verify with this paragraph.

\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    This is solution~1.
\end{solution}


\begin{test}
    This is a test environment.

    Notice, that you jump to the right paragrpah using reverse synctex (from document to source).

    You can also verify with this paragraph.


\end{test}

\begin{testthm}
    This is a testthm environment.

    Notice that reverse synctex (from document to source) works, despite this environment being based on trivlist.

    You can also verify with this paragraph.
\end{testthm}
\end{document}
```

I would like to find a workaround or fix to achieve the expected behaviour.

[image: behaviour demonstration]